# Converting $\sin^{-1}u$ to $\tan^{-1}v$

Tags: trigonometry

Say that we have the two equations$$\sin 3\theta=\frac {12a-14-A-8Aa}{2(4a-A)^{3/2}}=:u_1$$
and
$$\sin3\theta=\frac {12a-14+A+8Aa}{2(4a+A)^{3/2}}=:u_2.$$

How do we simplify $u_1$ and $u_2$ to get$$\sin^{-1}(-u_1)=\tan^{-1}\frac {2A-1}{3\sqrt{3}}$$$$\sin^{-1}u_2=\tan^{-1}\frac {2A+1}{3\sqrt3}$$Where $A=\sqrt{4a-7}$.

---

The book said that if you draw a right triangle with sides $2A\pm1$ and $3\sqrt3$, then the hypotenuse is $2\sqrt{4a\pm A}$. And thus, to demonstrate the two equations are equal, we need to prove$$\frac {2A-1}{2\sqrt{4a-A}}=\frac {-12a+14+A+8Aa}{2(4a-A)^{3/2}}$$$$\frac {2A+1}{2\sqrt{4a+A}}=\frac {12a-14+A+8Aa}{2(4a+A)^{3/2}}$$

---

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. How do you know to draw a right triangle whose side lengths are $2A\pm1$ and $3\sqrt3$?
> 2. How to you get from proving the trigonometric equalities, to proving$$\frac {2A\pm1}{2\sqrt{4a\pm A}}=\frac {\pm12a\mp14+A+8Aa}{2(4a\pm A)^{3/2}} ?$$

I'm just really confused. I tried drawing the right triangle. But that didn't quite help me too much because we're dealing with $\sin^{-1}\theta$ and $\tan^{-1}\theta$. Anybody have any ideas you have that can help me?

Comment: Here you can find hundreds of formulas http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSin/27/02/03/01/05/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Question 2: the equality

$$\frac {2A\pm1}{2\sqrt{4a\pm A}}=\frac {\pm12a\mp14+A+8Aa}{2(4a\pm A)^{3/2}}$$

is equivalent to

$$ {2A\pm1}=\frac {\pm12a\mp14+A+8Aa}{(4a\pm A)},$$

since
${(4a\pm A)^{3/2}} = (4a\pm A)\sqrt{4a\pm A} $.

Do you see how to simply from here (using $A^2 = 4a-7$)?